# msbuild - String.Replace causes replacement of ";" with "%3B"

Tags: msbuild

[Target Element (MSBuild)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx)

***Inputs***: Optional attribute.
The files that form inputs into this target. Multiple files are separated by semicolons. The timestamps of the files will be compared with the timestamps of files in Outputs to determine whether the Target is up to date. For more information, see Incremental Builds, How to: Build Incrementally, and Transforms.

I separate my files with semicolons as the documentation states.

Furthermore, in the command (aka recipe) that uses these files, they are consumed!

**QUESTION**
Why is `MSBuild` telling me none of the inputs exist?

The XML is:

```
<Target Name="micropython_prebuild_create_qstrdefs" Inputs="$(uP_PrebuildSrc)" Outputs="$(uP_GenHdrFolder)\qstrdefs.generated.h">
```

The output is:

> Input file "Source\py\vm.c;Source\py\vstr.c;Source\py\warning.c" does
>   not exist.

**UPDATE**

I found where the log looks iffy.
***XML***:

```
<Target Name="micropython_prebuild">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PreBuildProperties> 
        uP_PrebuildPyExe="$(ProjectDir)\Source\micropython\py\make_prebuild_wrapper.exe";   
        uP_GenHdrFolder=$(ObjectFolder)\genhdr;
        uP_QSTR_GEN_EXTRA_CFLAGS=-DNO_QSTR -DN_X64 -DN_X86 -DN_THUMB -DN_ARM -DN_XTENS;
        uP_SrcFolder=$(ProjectDir)\Source\micropython;
        uP_MpyCrossExe="$(ProjectDir)\Source\micropython\mpy-cross\mpy-cross.exe";
        uP_PrebuildSrc=$(CppFiles.Replace('Source\micropython\minimal\frozen_mpy.c;',''));
        </PreBuildProperties>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <MakeDir Directories="$(ObjectFolder)\genhdr" />

    <MSBuild
        Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
        Condition="'' == ''"
        Targets="micropython_prebuild_mpversion"
        Properties="$(PreBuildProperties)"
    />
...
```

***Log:***

```
Task "MSBuild" (TaskId:7)
  Task Parameter:Projects=ATI_micropython.vcxproj (TaskId:7)
  Task Parameter:Targets=micropython_prebuild_mpversion (TaskId:7)
  Task Parameter:
      Properties=
uP_PrebuildSrc=Source\micropython\extmod\machine_i2c.c;Source\micropython\extmod\machine_mem.c;

Global Properties: (TaskId:7)
uP_PrebuildSrc=Source\micropython\extmod\machine_i2c.c%3bSource\micropython\extmod\machine_mem.c%3b
```

For testing, if I change the line   `uP_PrebuildSrc=$(CppFiles.Replace('Source\micropython\minimal\frozen_mpy.c;',''));`
to
`uP_PrebuildSrc=$(CppFiles);`
I do **NOT** get the weird `%3b` character in `uP_PrebuildSrc`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you show an example project file that reproduces this? Which version of msbuild are you using?

Comment: @MartinUllrich actual file is 600 lines. I updated questions with relevant section.

Comment: How is the `uP_PrebuildSrc` set? I suspect there may be escaping issues going on here. a variable that is commonly used as inputs is `$(MSBuildAllProjects)` which contains semicolons as well

Comment: @MartinUllrich away from desk now but I think you’re right: I remember seeing weird characters in log file for SOME property where the semicolon was replaced by some hex chars. Will investigate tomorrow.

Comment: Just checking, but are you aware that genhdr.targets in the msvc port directory of MicroPython already has this functionality, and seems to be parametrized enough so that you can reuse it?

Comment: @stijn at this point, it's too late but if I ever refactor things it would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I updated it. Turns out the `Replace` function was causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder class with AppendFormat() gives wrong results too so I guess it is not just a matter of Replace function as You suggest.
Reproduced the issue using inline task with following operation:

```
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System"/>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
          builder.AppendFormat("{0}:={1};", file.GetMetadata("FullPath"), linuxFile);
          FileMap += builder.ToString();
      ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
```

This was attempt to use $(AdditionalSourcesToCopyMapping) with C++ Linux project.
Then in the output log i see my FileMap split with "%3b" characters instead of ";".
Anybody suspecting possible cause why this happens?